# JUnit test failed to read property file from another module class

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, gradle, junit4

I am creating a project which have multiple module.I am using the gradle build tool and IntelliJ IDEA.I have two module webservice and utilities.
Project Structure as-[image]

I am reading the config.properties file in my utilities module.In which I am defining the server port and other values. When I am calling the method of utilities module (which reads the property file and return the values) from my webservice module classes that work fine and return proper values.
But when trying to call same method from test classes of webservice module then utility class method failed to read property file.

Now I am not getting what is going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the property file exists in /src/test/resources as well as /src/main/resources as the classpath used when executing tests differs to your regular application classpath.

Comment: thanks for answer. But I have multiple module and test classes for respective modules and all the module accessing the global config file which is place under a directory in master directory and  I am loading them via utility module and all the other module able to read from utility module but test classes not. Is there is any way so test classes of all module can read from single place?

Comment: It should be able to work. But I don't know what is causing your problem.

Comment: public static String ReadConfigProperties(String propName){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            logger.info("Reading property name: " + propName);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(ServerGlobals.ProjectConfigFolder + "/" + ServerGlobals.ProjectConfigFile);
            properties.load(inputStream);
            result =  properties.getProperty(propName);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return result;
    }

Comment: I am using above method to load and read property files. Is it possible to call this method from my test classes?

Comment: Error while executing this line: inputStream = new FileInputStream(ServerGlobals.ProjectConfigFolder + "/" + ServerGlobals.ProjectConfigFile); Cant not find file specified

Comment: Can you print out the values of ServerGlobals.ProjectConfigFolder  and ServerGlobals.ProjectConfigFile just before the error occurs to confirm that it is looking in the correct location?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help, not sure what is wrong here